# Linking ibus (libibus), glib in cmake

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I am making a IME with iBus. I am wanting to use cmake as build environment. But there is no documentation about linking iBus(libibus). I need glib also. My coding language is C, C++. I need help please!

Thanks
Sorry for bad English!

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I haven't worked with ibus and glib

Answer (score 1):

To use glib and iBus(libibus) in cmake, you have to use pkgconfig module. Here is a example :

```
## Find GLib and iBus ##
FIND_PACKAGE(PkgConfig)
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GLIB2 REQUIRED glib-2.0)
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(IBUS REQUIRED ibus-1.0)
```

The `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` function defines some variables to use them to link with your program. You can use them like these:

```
## Include and Link
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${GLIB2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${IBUS_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${GLIB2_LIBRARY_DIRS} ${IBUS_LIBRARY_DIRS})

## Create your Executable and link it. `.....` your sources
ADD_EXECUTABLE(My_Prog .....)
## `....` place your created libraries
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(My_Prog ${GLIB2_LIBRARIES} ${IBUS_LIBRARIES} ....)
```

Thanks!